# C - gdb debugger does not execute fscanf in VScode

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

I am currenty working on my first programming project in C and have some trouble with the minGW GDB debugger. the application I am writing is suppposed to read strings and float variables from a txt file.
Everything works when I run it in the powershell terminal. However when I run the program with the debugger, the fscanf functions don't read the strings and variables out of the text file.
This is the code with the fscanf function: (I have written this code for demonstration, so what it does is kinda pointless.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char car[20];
    float length;
}CARS;

int main()
{
    CARS cartype[20];
    FILE *carlist; // stores list of cars and their length
    int retReadCar; //check wheather input is valid

    // scan list of cartypes into the structure
    carlist = fopen("doc2.txt", "r");

    int scanelement = 0;
    do
    {
        retReadCar = fscanf(carlist, "%s %f", cartype[scanelement].car, &cartype[scanelement].length);
        scanelement++;
    }while(retReadCar == 2);
    fclose(carlist);


    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf("car: %s, length: %4.2f\n",  cartype[j].car, cartype[j].length);
    }
}
```

This is the launch.json file:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Aktive Datei erstellen und debuggen",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\bin",
            "environment": [],
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\mingw-w64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Automatische Strukturierung und Einrückung für \"gdb\" aktivieren",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe Aktive Datei kompilieren"
        }
    ]
```

the text file "doc2.txt" looks like this:

```
mercedes 4.23
audi 3.28
cadillac 4.56
```

Comment: The cause might be wrong placement of the data file `doc2.txt` compared to the working directory used when launched from the debugger. Check the result of `fopen()`.

Comment: Yes, thats it. thank you so much. i just set "cwd" in launch.json to the path of the "doc2.txt" file and it works.